# Please help. I get this error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF while parsing"

Tags: python

```
try:
  f1=int(input("enter first digit"))
  f2=int(input("enter second digit"))

  answ=(f1/f2)
  print (answ)
except ZeroDivisionError:
```

Comment: I don't see the justification for the downvotes here. I think this specific syntax error is cryptic since it can be caused by any number of reasons. And simply looking at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) for handling exceptions, that may not be enough. While the syntax `except SomeError: pass` is mentioned in there, it is not made explicit that a block must not be left empty, which can be puzzling for a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have an `except` line with nothing after it. You have to have *some* code there, even if it doesn't do anything.

```
try:
  f1=int(input("enter first digit"))
  f2=int(input("enter second digit"))

  answ=(f1/f2)
  print (answ)
except ZeroDivisionError:
  pass
```

Comment: @hunk `pass` is used for these kind of situations where you have to put something in a block, but you either want to implement it later or or leave it empty.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, when you write ':', you start a code block. And, as per syntax you can't keep a block empty.

So, you must complete the block.e.g.

```
try :
    f1=int(input("enter first digit"))
    f2=int(input("enter second digit"))
    answ=(f1/f2)
    print (answ)
except ZeroDivisionError::
    print ("You can't divide by zero")
```

Comment: Syntax error in line 6.  **::** should be replaced by **:**